# How can I convert numbers to word in PHP?

Tags: php

I have foreach loop in PHP and it has words such as "one" as you can see below code.I need write words for every foreach loop item.For example, "one" and for second item "two" etc.

So, I need a variable and it will be increased for every item and its value will write in html class as word.

In Simplest way, how can I do it?

```
 <?php   if ( $settings['hekim_feature_list_department'] ) {
                                        foreach (  $settings['hekim_feature_list_department'] as $item ) { ?>

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                <i class="icon-Down-2 icon-1"></i>
                                                <i class="icon-Right-2 icon-2"></i>
                                                <?php echo $item['hekim_feature_list_title_department'];?>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <p><?php echo $item['hekim_team_member_description_department'];?></p>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use identifiers with numbers instead e.g. `id="collapse1"`?

Comment: I think OP wants unique numbers ? if so, you can use hekim ID instead of numbers, example : `id="collapse<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"` this will be unique, auto increased what ever.

Comment: @Dlk you are right, I solved by uniqid(); thanks for your idea

Comment: Glad I helped :)